# Does Flux.collectList() introduce blocking behavior

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux

Assume we have a Finder that returns multiple objects

```
fun findAll(): Flux<CarEntity> {
    return carRepository.findAll()
}
```

Because we want to apply some logic to all cars and passengers at the same time, we convert it to a Mono through `.collectList()`

```
val carsMono = carsFinder.findAll().collectList()
val passengerMono = carsFinder.findAll().collectList()

return Mono.zip(carsMono, passengerMono)
```

In other words,

1. We have a list of entities of undefined length
2. We gather every item in a list until there is no more - how is this done without blocking the threat?

Comment: Very often it's required to convert Flux to Mono<List> and vise versa. `collectList` returns `Mono<List<T>>` and is not blocking. Another useful operator is `Flux.buffer` that allows to implement batching logic.

Comment: think of it like a worker at a factory conveyer belt. When something comes along the belt ha takes it places the item in a shipping box. Then he does something else until something again comes flying down the conveyer belt. He takes that item and places it in the same shipping box. Then repeat this process until the box is full, ha decides to ship the box. What i just described is `collectList`

Comment: @Toerktumlare 'until the box is full' implies there's a termination signal. The conveyer belt itself is blocked by the box being filled, even though the worker is doing different things in between. So instead of having a consitent data flow, there one blob in between that grows until it bursts - maybe blocking is not the right word here but it feels like it's breaking the data flow.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. CollectList returns a list of N length, so yes there has to be a termination signal saying that there are no more items. Ship the box. Blocking in my analogy would mean that the worker stands by the belt all the time. It has nothing to do with the belt itself. And the box is not blocking, it is collecting. As the function name implies.

Comment: @Toerktumlare As long as it's collecting, the program flow halts. And this indefinitely or 'until the termination signal arrives'. So it can potentially break a program flow if no termination signal is received. This would be non-blocking on thread level - which is what your conveyer belt example is about - but halt processing of a request potentially indefinitely.

Comment: you have missunderstood the concep of "blocking". If the program is always collecting becuase you have given it a infinite list, its still not blocking. Blocking is when we have for instance a thread waiting and doing noting. That would be that the man stands by the box constantly waiting even though there are no items on the belt. If there are a constant 100% flow of items so that he has to pack things all the time. We are still not blocking.

Comment: As pointed out in the answer given, using `collectList` on an infinite stream is not something i would not recommend though, not in combination without for instance the `buffer` operator. Your question was `is it blocking` the answer is straight out no. Could you end up in a deadlock? then the answer is yes. Deadlocks and blocking are two different things

Comment: you have written "list of undefined length" which means it has a finite length it is just undefined, which also means there will be a termination signal. You have not written "is of infinite length" which implies it has no length and thus no termination signal.

Comment: Would deadlock be the right terminology for describing this? So far I only considered deadlocking when there's simultaneous resource access happening. I do get what blocking is usually used for but so far I fail to properly describe this 'resource clogging' or 'blocking process flow' - as I said, I wouldn't consider using deadlock in this case as it's misleading (for myself)

Answer (score 3):

No collectList() is not a blocking operator but we need to be careful when we use this operator.

with this operator we wait till the upper stream has emitted all elements to us, and if this stream is never ending stream like kafkatemplate or a processor, the collect list will collect elements till it run in out of memory exception.

Or when we have a big stream like findAll from database this will collect a big list consuming a lot of ram memory or even giving out of memory exception.
If you know that you deal with small number of elements you are safe to go.

If you can avoid and process elements in stream than would be better